How can I improve performance of a MySQL query with complicated WHERE logic?
I maintain my own homemade music organization app, with which I can write complicated rules to build playlists. These result in somewhat complicated SQL queries to capture the logic.
For example, here's one such query, slightly simplified:
SELECT id FROM tracks
WHERE 
(
    eligibility = 2 AND(
        artist IN(
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"
        ) OR (
            rating >= 3 AND(
                artist IN(
                    "G", "H", "I"
                ) OR genre = "Rock"
            )
        )
    )
);

In English, this starts from a set of "eligible" tracks. Then it grabs all tracks from artists A-F, then grabs all tracks with 3+ stars that have genre Rock or are from artists G-I.
With 50,000 rows in tracks, these take a while to execute, even with indices on eligibility, artist, rating, and genre.
What are some things I could try to improve performance?

always start with execution plan

Even without indices a query against a table of 50000 rows should not take a while - what do you mean by take a while. Also please publish table definition as text.

The word "performance" and the IN operator don't belong to the same sentence.

Please edit to ask a very specific question, with all relevant details (a [mcve], showing sample schema, sample data, expected vs actual behavior, etc). Right now, it's one example query, with no specific issues other than "takes a while to execute" which isn't a quantifiable thing.

What percentage of the table has eligibility = 2 ?  OR is hard to optimize.  If the query is more complex than what you show, advice here may (or may not) apply.
